# Vmware Workstation how to hide the top bar and still be able to use multiple monitor

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I know how to enable multiple monitors.
I know how to totally hiding that top bar.
However, I don't know how to enable multiple monitors after hiding the top bar.

In order to get into multiple monitors, so far I can find the only way is to use the top bar and cycle through different monitors layouts.
Is there a hot key to switch to all monitors? Or is there anyway to let Vmware to remember the last monitors layout? Or is there anyway to configure always using all monitors at vm boot time?

The reason I tried to hide the top bar, is because I am using a dark theme. That top bar, even after it auto hide, there is still a strip of few pixel wide on the top of the screen. That strip is too bright in contrast with my dark theme.
I wish there is an option to change the top bar color.